# Encryption in HBase

Tags: java, encryption, hbase

I want to store data in hbase as encrypted and decrypt it when i fetch it. What is the best way to do so. Is there only way to encrypt it and store into hbase and then decrypt it while reading.

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know you can only use encryption in network layer for hbase. But I might be wrong!!! Also, I don't understand the use-case of a encrypted data especially in hadoop which is mostly used for processing of large amounts of data.

Comment: I want to store encrypted data in hbase to secure it from illegal access.

Comment: Then secure access to your file-system by allowing only localhost to access, and implement network security instead of encrypted entire DB.

Comment: ps: hbase has cell level security feature. https://blogs.apache.org/hbase/entry/hbase_cell_security   And I think i saw an article about it in cloudera engineering blog too.